# r function access local string variable

Tags: r

I'm trying to write a function to print out a pdf of some graph. I would like my function to take 2 arguments (options): the dataset which I will draw my graphs from and a string variable which is used for the pdf file name. How do I pass the string to a command within the function? my code is :

```
 plot_all_layout <- function(network, filename){
    layouts <- grep("^layout_", ls("package:igraph"), value=TRUE)[-1] 
      # Remove layouts that do not apply to our graph.
      layouts <- layouts[!grepl("bipartite|merge|norm|sugiyama|tree", layouts)]

      par(mfrow=c(3,3), mar=c(1,1,1,1))
      pdf("filename.pdf") #here is where I would like to call the local var

      for (layout in layouts) {
        print(layout)
        l <- do.call(layout, list(network)) 
        plot(network, edge.arrow.mode=0, layout=l, main=layout) }
      dev.off()
      par(mfrow=c(1,1)
  }
```

Comment: Is "filename.pdf" the string for a variable in R or the name of a pdf-file in some directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use `pdf(paste0(filename, ".pdf"))`

Hope this helps.